# Rule-based classifying (styling) by multiple fields in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

I need to build an expression through which to achieve a rule-based classification by multiple fields.
The basic expression could be:
"Field 1" = 'Value a' AND "Field 2" = 'Value b' AND "Field 3" = 'Value c'
but I need to be able to write in the same rule n expression with the same structure but referring to different values of the same fields, ie
[image]

so that each class is composed of the set of elements (features) that satisfy the conditions of the single basic expression.
As a second possibility to obtain the same classification I considered the possibility of creating a new column whose values are obtained through a CASE WHEN / THEN expression that contains the same expressions described above, ie:
[image]

Can both be correct ways to solve the problem and what can be the correct syntax?

Comment: did you try to combine different combinations with 'OR'.  So: ("Field 1" = 'Value a' AND "Field 2" = 'Value b' AND "Field 3" = 'Value c') OR ("Field 1" = 'Value x' AND "Field 2" = 'Value y' AND "Field 3" = 'Value z') ?

Comment: Not yet, thanks. I would like to ask:
in this way will all the values that satisfy each expression be included in the classification?
in this case is the use of brackets correct?

Comment: it al depends on the logic you want to use.  In my example the result between the brackets will be evaluated one by one. It is a combination of the 3 fields in the brackets that will be evaluated.

Comment: Your hint has solved the problem perfectly ... it seems to work very well! (I'm testing on different layers) thanks a lot!

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to to combine the different combinations with 'OR'.

So: `("Field 1" = 'Value a' AND "Field 2" = 'Value b' AND "Field 3" = 'Value c') OR ("Field 1" = 'Value x' AND "Field 2" = 'Value y' AND "Field 3" = 'Value z')`

The combination of the 3 fields within the brackets will be evaluated one by one.